# How to combine Angular 6 and Codeigniter 3 in my web project, so that Angular manages the frontend and Codeigniter manages the backend?

Tags: php, typescript, codeigniter-3, angular6, scaffolding

I want to buid a web app that uses **Angular 6** to manage the *frontend* and **Codeigniter 3** for *backend*. The problem is that I don't know how to combine the two, and all the tutorials I looked were using ***AngularJS*** which is the *version 1* whereas i'm using *version 6*, and it didn't really work.

I am looking for something like [JavaScript & CSS Scaffolding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend) using **Angular 6** (and not *AngularJS*) with **Codeigniter 3**

What I want is to set the view to be the Angular app and let Codeigniter do the routing and handle the server.

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 1):

You can create components, which interact codeigniter on angular 6. GET and POST requests request to your API which located in your backend code.

Example here:

```
 export class SomeClass implements OnInit {

    private API_ENDPOINT = 'codeigniter_functions_url_can_be_here';
    private headers;
        constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
            this.headers = new Headers();
            this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

          }

         this.http.get(this.API_ENDPOINT, { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(res => {
              cb(res);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create APi's in codeigniter and then implement those in Angular or any other front end language.

Comment: I forgot to tell I am new to this, so please can you tell me exactly how to do that or redirect me to a place where I can find that? Thanks.

Comment: Typescript scaffolding (with Angular 6) using Codeigniter 3??

Comment: @AaravAcharya watch this tutorial hope you can understand
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2i-rt0yxDQ